# Best way to write this query?

Tags: mysql, join, subquery, query-optimization, inner-join

I am doing a sub-query join to another table as I wanted to be able to sort the results I got back with it, I only need the first row but I need them ordered in a certain way so I would get the lowest id.

I tried adding `LIMIT 1` to this but then the full query returned 0 results; so now it has no limit and in the `EXPLAIN` I have two rows showing they are using the full 10k+ rows of the `auction_media` table.

I wrote it this way to avoid having to query the `auction_media` table for each row separately, but now I'm thinking that this way isn't that great if it has to use the whole auction_media table?

Which way is better? The way I have it or querying the `auction_media` table separately? ...or is there a better way!?

Here is the code:

```
SELECT 
    a.auction_id,
    a.name,
    media.media_url
FROM 
    auctions AS a 
    LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.user_id=a.owner_id 
    INNER JOIN ( SELECT media_id,media_url,auction_id 
                         FROM auction_media 
                         WHERE media_type=1 
                          AND upload_in_progress=0 
                         ORDER BY media_id ASC
            ) AS media 
            ON a.auction_id=media.auction_id 
WHERE a.hpfeat=1 
  AND a.active=1 
  AND a.approved=1 
  AND a.closed=0 
  AND a.creation_in_progress=0 
  AND a.deleted=0 
  AND (a.list_in='auction' OR u.shop_active='1') 
GROUP BY a.auction_id;
```

**Edit:** Through my testing, using the above query seems like it would be the much faster method overall; however I worry if that will still be the case when the `auction_media` table grows to like 1M rows or something.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ - better way to ask this art of question.

Comment: You **only need the first row**. Does that mean you want only 1 row returned - which would then limit your query to 1 auction_id? Or do you want 1 row returned per auction_id with the lowest media_id for that auction_id?

Comment: @aldanux I actually *tried* to post it there but had trouble logging-in/signing up for an account with the same email.

Comment: @AgRizzo Sorry, what I meant by only one row is.... I only need 1 row from the *sub-query* join (the first result), but I want all matching results for the entire query if that make sense.

Comment: @Brett you really need to learn about `Group By`.  You aren't aggregating the other objects in any way. Any other DBMS would throw an error when executing this query as it is illogical. This is another in a long line of SO questions where if MySQL had proper `GROUP BY` logic would not exist.

Comment: @Zane I tried using `DISTINCT` but it's slower AND it returns more rows than I want.

Comment: @Brett well you're going to want to determine a Criteria for getting the rows you want and apply them to your query. I don't know what else to tell you since rows you want isn't something I have a measure for.

Comment: I just noticed the reason it was returning more rows is cause it's getting a distinct value based on the 3 columns I am selecting, rather than just the `aucton_id` column. Though in saying that, it's still slower.

Comment: By gum, look how fast the result is! Sure, it's not correct but it's fast. The users will love fast.

Comment: Could you precise what is a subject of the question ? Dou you want to optimize the query shown in the question ? Or, as I understood, this query gives wrong results, and you want to correct the query to get proper results (but in this case the optimization of the wrong query is aimless).

Comment: @billinkc Well yes, they will....... that and it's returning the correct results :)

Comment: @kordirko No, the query returns the correct results, I'm just wondering if it could be improved more so it didn't have to use pretty much the whole result set of the `auction_media` table via the sub-query.

Comment: Ok, then the first step is to remove `ORDER BY media_id ASC` clause from the subquery, since it has no any effect - the resultset of this subquery is joined in the main query, and it's order is lost. Then try to rewrite the subquery uning inner join directly in the main query, MySql is not good in optimizing subqueries.

Comment: @kordirko Why would I want to remove the `ORDER BY media_id ASC`? That's what makes sure I get the correct row returned; this does order it correctly as if I change it to `DESC` then the results I get back change.

Comment: This query is using `mysql group by extension`. Please read this link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-extensions.html especially this: `The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate.  Furthermore, the selection of values from each group cannot be influenced by adding an ORDER BY clause......`.The query seems to work, but "by accident", some day (for example in a new version of MySql) it can start to give different results, an no one can complain-they clearly wrote: `MySql is free to choose any value`.

Comment: @kordirko I may be wrong, but I thought that the `GROUP BY` had no effect on the sub-query and only the resulting main query and hence it shouldn't affect the `ORDER BY` and hence the `ORDER_BY` should always return the correct row first.

Comment: @Brett the point that all these guys are making is that your correct results are by accident only. A future MySQL upgrade may well break your query and make it return irrelevant data. Why don't make it correct and fast now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*edit: As stated in the comments - `DISTINCT` is not required because the auctions table can only be associated with (at most) one user table row and one row in the inner query.*

You may want to try this. <strike>The outer query's GROUP BY is replaced with DISTINCT since you don't have any aggregate function.</strike> The inner query, was replaced by a query to find the smallest media_id per auction_id, then JOINed back to get the media_url. (Since I didn't know if the media_id and auction_id were a composite unique key, I used the same WHERE clause to help eliminate potential duplicates.)

```
SELECT
    a.auction_id,
    a.name,
    auction_media.media_url
FROM auctions AS a 
LEFT JOIN users AS u 
  ON u.user_id=a.owner_id 
INNER JOIN (SELECT auction_id, MIN(media_id) AS media_id
            FROM auction_media 
            WHERE media_type=1 
               AND upload_in_progress=0 
            GROUP BY auction_id) AS media 
  ON a.auction_id=media.auction_id 
INNER JOIN auction_media
  ON auction_media.media_id = media.media_id
    AND auction_media.auction_id = media.auction_id
    AND auction_media.media_type=1 
    AND auction_media.upload_in_progress=0 
WHERE a.hpfeat=1 
  AND a.active=1 
  AND a.approved=1 
  AND a.closed=0 
  AND a.creation_in_progress=0 
  AND a.deleted=0 
  AND (a.list_in='auction' OR u.shop_active='1');
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Though *at the moment* it is slightly *slower* than the original query I had, but it's something I'm going to keep on hand for future testing when the auction_media table grows.

Comment: The `DISTINCT` can be removed.